# Have same URL for two separate pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on testing different landing pages for users, and want 50% to land on a different page. The split is being done based on odd/even IP address. However, I want the URL of the landing page to be the same, but can't figure out how to do this. So far these are the two ActionResults:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult VerifyVoucherCode()
    {
        var model = new VerifyVoucherModel();

        model.ActivationCode = Request.GetFirstQueryValue("value", "voucher");

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AlternateVerifyVoucherCode()
    {
        var model = new VerifyVoucherModel();

        model.ActivationCode = Request.GetFirstQueryValue("value", "voucher");

        return View(model);
    }
```

As you can see the code is exactly the same, which I want to avoid regardless, but they correspond with different .cshtml files and partials and display different content. I want the URL for both to be 'SignUp/VerifyVoucher' but the second one is obviously at the moment 'SignUp/AlternateVerifyVoucher'. Is there any way I can get the `AlternateVerifyVoucherCode` to have the same URL but display and match up with the different razor pages?

Comment: Just use one ActionResult for your URL but testing ip in it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need one entry point with mutliple results. Maybe something like this pseudo code?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult VerifyVoucherCode()
    {
        var model = new SomeModel();
        if (something == verifyvoucher)
        {
            return View("VerifyVoucherCode", model);
        }
        else if (something == alternateverifyvoucher)
        {
            return View("AlternateVerifyVoucherCode", model);
        }
        else
        {
            //TODO: error
            return View("SomeError");
        }
    }
```